# My project title is not being reflected in pdf overview in Overleaf

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{A Comparative Study of Reliability of Database Systems Using RAID}
\author{John}
\date{April 2021}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage{multicol}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Abstract}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly issue `\maketitle` after `\begin{document}`.